# BreezeJs - Sending PATCH and PUT

Tags: breeze

i have built web api service which expose OData how ever it seems that currently there are problems when using Batch commands. i wanted to know if i can use BreezeJS without the Batch commands

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on your question Can you clarify?

Comment: sure, i am working with the nightly builds of the webapi team and i am creating my EDM model (working with odata) with the builder - i am adding all the entities and relations. it seems that when i am calling from breeze accept changes - by default it use batch command to push all the changes, how ever it looks like the the web api has bugs in it, wanted to know if i can change the behavior of breeze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily, but doable.

In the breeze source on GitHub, take a look at the file "b00_breeze.dataService.odata.js". This is where we prepare the OData save. You can create your own dataService patterned on this one that does not do batching, but... you will lose all transaction guarantees if you do this.

If you think an 'unbatched OData save' would be useful please add a vote for it on the Breeze User Voice here ->: [breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions](http://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions)

Comment: thanks, i am fighting with the webapi odata, with the expand that is not working good i can over come but with the saving i need to give up and try your way

Comment: can find b00_breeze.dataService.odata.js

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  It's in "..GitHub\Breeze\Breeze.Client\Scripts\IBlade" folder